# docker: error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.39/containers/create: dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host

Tags: docker

I am new to `docker`. I am trying to convert a `docker` image into `singularity` by using the tool `docker2singularity`, but when I execute the command `docker run quay.io/singularity/docker2singularity my_image.tar`, I get the error in the following output:

```
Image Format: squashfs
Docker Image: my_image.tar

docker: error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.39/containers/create: dial tcp: 
lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know about this "singularity" but DNS would normally listen on UDP, and your output shows TCP